# SwiftUI warning ("Assert") from context menu

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, contextmenu

I'm relatively new to iOS development. Maybe I'm just overreacting, but I'd like to know what to do about this. I have a `ContentView`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
    
        Text("Favorite Card Suit")
            .padding()
            .contextMenu {
                Button("♥️ - Hearts", action: selectHearts)
            }
    }

    func selectHearts() {
        print("hearts")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I copied the relevant parts from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/contextmenu. It works, but in the XCode console it reads

> hearts 
> 2022-03-19 12:39:46.299344+0100 test[52717:2616062] [Assert] Trying to decrement *unsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspensionCount when it's already 0. We lost count one way or another, or else we had a stack recursion. self = <*TtGC7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier**: 0x148808ed0; frame = (0 0; 428 926); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000037e9d70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000039a2840>>

Comment: Is this the only view in your app? Using just the code you posted I was unable to reproduce this problem.

Comment: It's the only view. I created an iOS app and pasted into the ContentView what I found in the documentation. It seems to happen only the first time I click the context menu item.